# Getting error while assigning values to records inside collection

Tags: plsql, collections, record

I need to loop through some values inside the plsql code.
so trying to create a collection of records .
getting error as mentioned below.
Please help me to resolve

```
-- please see the code below  


    declare 
    type tab_name is record  (t_name varchar2(30),col_name varchar2(30));
    type tab_list is table of tab_name;
    table_names tab_list:=tab_list(tab_name('ABC','abc'),tab_name('XYZ','xyz'));
    begin
    for i in table_names.first..table_names.last loop
    dbms_output.put_line(table_names(i).t_name||'-'||table_names(i).col_name);
    end loop;
    end;
    /




    Error report -
    ORA-06550: line 4, column 32:
    PLS-00222: no function with name 'TAB_NAME' exists in this scope
    ORA-06550: line 4, column 13:
    PL/SQL: Item ignored
    ORA-06550: line 6, column 10:
    PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
    ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
    06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
    *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
    *Action:
```

Comment: You can't initialise a collection of records like that in the declaration section. See [this AskTOM question](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=initializing-a-plsql-table-of-records) for more info and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record type's name is not its initializer.
In fact, there is no initialization-like function for record types at all in oracle:

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#sthref1191)

> Note that values are assigned separately to each field of a record in
>   Example 5-47. You cannot assign a list of values to a record using an
>   assignment statement. There is no constructor-like notation for
>   records.

You have to create each object separately and then create collection with them:

```
declare 
    type tab_name is record  (t_name varchar2(30),col_name varchar2(30));
    type tab_list is table of tab_name;

    name_1 tab_name;

    table_names tab_list;
begin
   name_1.t_name := 'ABC';
   name_1.col_name := 'abc';
   table_names := tab_list();
   table_names.extend;
   table_names(table_names.last) := name_1;
   name_1.t_name := 'XYZ';
   name_1.col_name := 'xyz';
   table_names.extend;
   table_names(table_names.last) := name_1;

    for i in table_names.first..table_names.last 
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(table_names(i).t_name||'-'||table_names(i).col_name);
    end loop;
end;
```

Collections DO have initializers. However, in your case you have a collection of record types, so you would have to have your records pre-created to make use of it.